# jQuery DataTable columns based on if condition

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Can we do `if` condition for jQuery dataTables columns? Based on variable value, I want to decide which column to show / hide.

I tried to achieved this, by creating an object and pass it to the `DataTable()` function by extracting the columns using spread operator as below:

```
if (offer = "offer1") {
  const offerCols = {
    "columns": [
      {"data": "ioName", "class": "align-middle"},
      {"data": "salesPrice","class": "align-middle"},                    
      {"data": "offerPrice","class": "align-middle"},            
      {"data": "offerQty","class": "align-middle"}, 
    ],
  } 
} else {
  const offerCols = {
    "columns": [
      {"data": "ioName", "class": "align-middle"},
      {"data": "salesPrice","class": "align-middle"},                    
      {"data": "offerPrice","class": "align-middle"},            
      {"data": "offerQty","class": "align-middle"},           
      {"data": "validPeriod","class": "align-middle"}, 
    ], 
  }              
}              


var $table = $("#table").DataTable({  
  "ajax": '/view_offers.php',

  ...offerCols,

  "classes": {
    sLength: "text-left w-auto",
  }
})
```

But, this not works for me. How do I solve the below issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a conditional column for viewing data then the answer is **YES**. but I don't understand why spread operator.

Below is the code of custom column rendering based on condition.

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
    [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
    [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
    [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
    [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
    [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
    [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
    [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sydney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
    [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
    [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
    [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
    [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
    [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
    [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sydney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
    [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
    [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
    [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];
function getConditionalColumn(isAdmin){
  var columns= [];
  if(isAdmin){
    columns.push({ title: "Name" }) 
      columns.push({ title: "Position" }) 
      columns.push({ title: "Office" })
        columns.push({ title: "Extn" }) 
      columns.push({ title: "Start date" }) 
      columns.push({ title: "Salary" })
  }
  else{
       columns.push({ title: "Name" }) 
      columns.push({ title: "Position" }) 
      columns.push({ title: "Office" })
  }
  return columns;
} 
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns:getConditionalColumn(false)//toggle here to see conditional column , put true for admin view and false for user view
    });
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell how this work in multiple conditions (if, elseif, elseif, else) etc.

Comment: @user3733831 as you can see there is one function for custom render you can put your if else condition over there and put your necessary column into column array.

Answer (score 0):

The object in `columns` has a [visible](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) property which accepts a `boolean`. So if you have other options to set on your columns then perhaps a neater solution would be:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'name',
            title: 'Name'
        },
        {
            data: 'salary',
            title: 'Salary',
            className: 'align-end',
            visible: isAdmin
        }
    ]
});
```

If you want to specify multiple conditions, simply have a function that returns a boolean:

```js
{
    data: 'salary',
    title: 'Salary',
    className: 'align-end',
    visible: setConditions()
}
```

```js
function setConditions() {
    if(condition1) return true;

    if(condition2) return true;

    return false;
}
```